# How to pass props with NavigationActions

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im trying to pass props with

```
NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Places' })
```

in my reducer. Then in my 'Places' route, I connect it with

```
var mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    name: state.name
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlacesScreen);
```

Does anybody know why props arent being assigned? Im new to React and would love some help figuring this out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not enough information but from the code, it looks like you are not getting data from the right part of you redux store. Every reducer creates a section in your redux store. Say you have a places reducer, in mapStateToProps, you should use state.places.name to get the data.
One quick way to debug this is to console.log the state in your mapStateToProps function to see what the state look like and where the data you want lives.

Comment: Yes thank you that really guided my debugging and I figured it out! Thank you!!